# Rank and exclude null values in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

Using Pyspark and the ntile function, I'm look for a way to deal with null values when I rank. The code below will rank the null values as well, as 1. I dont want that, I would like them to have rank null. And ranking only to be done on non-null values.

I can filter out null-values before the ranking, but then I need to join the null values back later due to my use-case.

Is there a way to only do the ranking on the values, exluding the null from the rank, and still keep all the rows?

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

#spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("PandasToSpark").getOrCreate()

data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15, 16, 18, 18, 19, 20],
                    'group':['A']*10 + ['B']*10,
'feature':[0.5, 3.4, 0.3, 0.1, 1.2, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 1.1, 2.2, np.nan, 1.32, 2.5, np.nan, 0.87, 1.56, 2.1, np.nan, 0.34, 7.43]})

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

window = Window.partitionBy(['group']).orderBy('feature')

spark_df =  spark_df.withColumn("feature_rank", F.ntile(5).over(window))

spark_df.display()
```

Comment: Why you have to join back null values, you can just union back the null values

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: Filter null values in df1, and non null values in df2, apply ntile on df2, then the result is df1 union df2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something as below -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

window = Window.partitionBy(['group']).orderBy(col('feature').asc_nulls_last())

df1 = spark_df.withColumn("feature_rank", when(col("feature").isNull(), None).otherwise(lit(0)))
df2 = df1.withColumn("feature_rank", when(col("feature").isNull(), col("feature_rank")).otherwise(ntile(5).over(window)))

df2.show()

+---+-----+-------+------------+
| ID|group|feature|feature_rank|
+---+-----+-------+------------+
|  4|    A|    0.1|           1|
|  3|    A|    0.3|           1|
|  1|    A|    0.5|           2|
|  9|    A|    1.1|           2|
|  5|    A|    1.2|           3|
|  7|    A|    2.0|           3|
| 10|    A|    2.2|           4|
|  2|    A|    3.4|           4|
|  6|    A|   null|        null|
|  8|    A|   null|        null|
| 19|    B|   0.34|           1|
| 15|    B|   0.87|           1|
| 12|    B|   1.32|           2|
| 16|    B|   1.56|           2|
| 18|    B|    2.1|           3|
| 13|    B|    2.5|           3|
| 20|    B|   7.43|           4|
| 11|    B|   null|        null|
| 14|    B|   null|        null|
| 18|    B|   null|        null|
+---+-----+-------+------------+
```

Here `asc_nulls_last()` -

> Returns a sort expression based on ascending order of the column, and null values appear after non-null values.

Comment: So if I want five rank groups I should set 6 when using this approach?

Comment: Yes. Think of it this way rank groups 1 through 5 for the non-null values and rank group 6 for null values.